# How to avoid game starting before start button is clicked?

Tags: unity, c#

I've made a game with a Title Screen (Canvas), and a Start Button attached to the Title Screen. Points, GameOver, Restart, and even the Start Button sort of works, but it's possible to play the game *before* the user presses start.

[image: Blue is player, pink is enemy, green is powerup.]

Is there a way to make the GameObjects only appear *after* the button is clicked? I've tried to move and change the "public void StartGame()", but I can't get it right.

This is my first game ever, so hope the code provided is relevant.

Enemy.cs

```
 void Start()
{
        enemyRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");    
}
```

GameManager.cs

```
 public void StartGame()
{
    powerup.transform.rotation);
    score = 0;
    UpdateScore(0);
    isGameActive = true;
    titleScreen.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
    enemyCount = FindObjectsOfType<Enemy>().Length;

    if (enemyCount == 0)
    {
        roundNumber++;
        SpawnEnemyIntruders(roundNumber);
        Instantiate(powerup, GenerateSpawnPosition(), powerup.transform.rotation);
    }
}

void SpawnEnemyIntruders(int enemiesToSpawn)

{
  for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToSpawn; i++)
  {
      int enemyIndex = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
      Instantiate(enemies[enemyIndex], GenerateSpawnPosition(), enemies[enemyIndex].gameObject.transform.rotation);
  }
}
public void GameOver()
{
    restartButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    gameOverText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    isGameActive = false;
}
```

PlayerController.cs

```
    void Start()
{
    playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    playerAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
```

StartButton.cs

```
    void Start()
{
    button = GetComponent<Button>();
    gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
    button.onClick.AddListener(StartThis);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome the community.

that is so simple. you need to define some flag for running of your game and instead of writing logic of start game in Start(){} function that is called on start of game object, you should call it for example on button press and make your update function that is called every frame only Work if a bool flag is True. i re-write your code for your approach:

```
public Button StartButtn;

public void StartGame
{
// everything on start function was called
}

 void Start()
{
StartButton.OnClick.AddListener(StartGame);
}

bool GameStarted;

void Update()
{
if(!GameStarted) return;
// everything that was called in update function

}
```

Comment: That's cool. *if(!isGameActive) return;* solved it for the enemies, and *if(!gameManager.isGameActive) return;* did it for the player.